# loop of ajax calls - accessing loop counter?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am stuck here, any help would be appreciated.

I have a listbox of items, and I want to retrieve data on each item in the list via AJAX (which calls a webservice).  The retrieved data needs to be manipulated based on which row it was called from.
If I pass in the row parameter, its value is always one greater than the number of rows.
Is there a way to pass in the value it had at the time the ajax call was initiated?

```
    var NumRows = list.options.length;
    for ( var row = 0; row < NumRows; row ++ )
    {
      var Value = list.options[row].value;
      var xmlHttpObj = CreateXmlHttpRequestObject();
      if ( xmlHttpObj != null )
      {
        xmlHttpObj.open( "POST", "Async.ashx?arg1=GetPhysicalPathInfo&arg2=" + Value, true );
        xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange = function ( row )
        {
          // code that needs to know what row we were from
        }
      }
      xmlHttpObj.send();
    }
```

Comment: this is a waste of HTTP requests (multi-ajax calls that is). does it have to be one at a time?

Comment: It is just that each request retrieves a sizable chunk of data.

Comment: nevermind, I'm just going to pass the row as an argument to the ajax request, and then pass it back in the return value.  Thanks for looking at this one.

Comment: what is this "list"? selectbox or a ul list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a closure with a self-executing function:

```
var NumRows = list.options.length;
for ( var row = 0; row < NumRows; row ++ )
{
  !function(row) {
      var Value = list.options[row].value;
      var xmlHttpObj = CreateXmlHttpRequestObject();
      if ( xmlHttpObj != null )
      {
        xmlHttpObj.open( "POST", "Async.ashx?arg1=GetPhysicalPathInfo&arg2=" + Value, true );
        xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
          // code that needs to know what row we were from
        }
      }
      xmlHttpObj.send();
  }(row);
}
```

Of course, it's a major red flag that you're issuing AJAX requests from a loop.  This is highly inefficient; consider making one call and returning an array from the server.

Comment: I have a large drawing area, and the loop is intended to allow parts of the drawing area to be populated as the info is available.  At the moment, it is taking several seconds to retrieve and populate the entire area on a single postback.

Comment: @WonderfulDay: That's fair.  I was just saying that *in general*, AJAX calls from a loop are a red flag.

Comment: It took a bit of playing around, but that looks like it did it - it was about isolating the row value, and ensuring that it was the value that was used by the asynchronous function.  Thank you!